# Where can I find this iPad mini wallpaper used in Apple's advert?

Tags: ipad

Can somebody help me find this wallpaper (image taken from http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/). I've looked all over the internet but couldn't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple sourced this image from [Robbie George Photography](http://robbiegeorgephotography.com/). It's called "Lake Mattamuskeet", you'll find it on his page.

Comment: Thank you! :-) Was trying to find it at least for a week but couldn't.

Comment: The asker is not reproducing the image created by Robbie George. The asker is correctly attributing the Apple advertisement featuring an image by Robbie George, which makes it a derivative work. As such the question is Fair Use. The answerer also provides a link to the original creator’s site, citing the title. It is no different than a shopper asking another customer where to find a half-remembered brand of a product on the shelf of a grocery store.

Answer (score 0):

One way it could be done is to take the image you posted, and using Photoshop or other graphics editing app, magic-wand select the image on the iPad, copy and paste into its own layer, select it again and use the Edit menu >Transform > Skew to square the corners. Then save the now relatively rectangular image as a JPG or whatever and use that as your background pic.

OR

Go to Google images and click on the camera icon:

[image]

Upload the file, and see what google finds for you. With luck, you'll find a hi-res royalty-free image.